# Which things are "cached" in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, caching, themes

I am worried about using WP functions several times in my themes.

If I use a function twice it's making a query twice? EG: "**get_stylesheet_directory()**" What if I used three times in different files: header, index and footer?

If I use get_option("some_option") three times with different options is worst than using wp_load_alloptions() and loading all of them at once and reusing the array?

I know with a plugin as wp super cache doesn't matter in the end, but I want to have a better understanding of how wordpress work.

Thanks

Comment: Take it as _What you ask is what you get_. And personally I think this is better than loading whole bunch of wp_options into some reusable array. Wp_options itself contain hundreds perhaps thousand of entries depends on sizes of the site. If I need 1 option why would I need to get and hold thousands of options ?

Comment: if get_option() make a database query and you make 10 different calls maybe, for performance sake, it's better to fetch them all and reuse the resulting array.
The main question is still unsolved, if you use get_option/get_stylesheet_directory/... twice does it make two diffent queries to the databese?

Comment: 'performance sake' agree. Wordpress is designed to use with blogs and as CMS for small sites. If you take this in consideration all your above mentioned points will justify itself. And part it depends on server too.

Comment: By the way this discussion is theoretical and doesn't seems to belong here. You can always create you custom functions to help you in developing what you asked.

Comment: Yes, I am creating an static class in my functions in order to "cache" all the info at once in the header and pass them to the rest of the site (instead of a global variable).

you have [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/diy-caching-methods-wordpress/) article saying how to cache things on WP you might found interesting